# How to calculate the euclidean distance between a 2-D tensor and a 3-D tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 2-D tensor **A** with the shape of (?, *L*) which refers to the features obtained through the neural network (where '?' is the batch size),  and a 3-D tensor **B** with the shape of (*N*, *K*, *L*). Obviously, there are *N* arrays with the shape of (*K*, *L*) in **B**, which are called **C** here.

Now, how can I calculate the **mean euclidean distance** (average the distance of one row of **A** and each row of **C**) between each row of **A** and every **C** without iterations of every rows in  **A** and **C**, and finally return a vector with the shape of (?, *N*) ?

For example, when the **A** with shape of (1, *L*), the result can be obtained as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None])
    B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
    dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(B - A, axis=2), axis=1)
    print(sess.run(dist, feed_dict={A: [[1, 2, 3]],
                                    B: [[[ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]],
                                        [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]]}))
    # [ 7.7942286 18.186533 ]
```

I want to know that when A = ([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]) (it is just an example of **A** with the shape of (2, 3)), how can I get the result of the question above with the shape of [2, 2] ?

Comment: We need some data and code to reproduce your problem. In addition, your attempts to achieve your goal are also missing.

Comment: I have clarified the problem and given an example, would you please help me solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None])
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
    a_exp = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(a, 1), 1)
    dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(b - a_exp, axis=3), axis=2)
    print(sess.run(dist, feed_dict={a: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
                                    b: [[[ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]],
                                        [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]]}))
    # [[ 7.7942286 18.186533 ]
    #  [ 2.598076  12.990381 ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    A = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None])
    B = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None])
    newA = tf.expand_dims(A, 0)
    dist = tf.reduce_mean(tf.norm(B - newA, axis=2), axis=1)
    print(sess.run(dist, feed_dict={A: [[1, 2, 3]],
                                    B: [[[ 4,  5,  6], [ 7,  8,  9]],
                                        [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15]]]}))
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it didn't work well. Assuming that a = ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]) with a shape of (2, 3) when the batch_size = 2, while b remains the value above. It is supposed that I should get the result with the shape of (2, 2), of which the first row equals [7.7942286 18.186533 ] is the distance between [1, 2, 3] and the 3-D tensor denoted a, and the second row equals[ 2.598076 12.990381] is the distance between [4, 5, 6] and a. But the code above returns the result [5.196152 15.588457] with the shape of (1, 2), it is obviously not correct.